# Ngrok endpoint provides expected response, but when I access the ec2 elastic ip endpoint, I get an error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I have a python code which recommends related user ids wrt to the input provided. I have named the flask app as app.py(running on port 8080) and uploaded it to my ec2 instance (running Ubuntu 20.x having Nginx setup). Now to deploy the application in production I have used Gunicorn. Below is the image which shows the service I have created to restart Gunicorn every time the instance is restarted.

[image]

Now whenever I send a GET API request to the ec2 elastic ip endpoint I get the following error:

[image]

Now this error generally indicates that there is a problem with the code. As the error indicates we are storing and using value from a function which has no return statement(Null). So I checked my code but I found no such function moreover I have not used .lower() anywhere in my code file.

To confirm that there is no issue with the code I decided to run the same flask app on Google Colab (which uses CentOS) and provided it a temporary global endpoint using Ngrok. This returned the output as expected which is shown in the below image. I am passing the same parameters in my GET request.

[image]

Now I am stuck and dont know why ec2 endpoint is throwing me this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Tried running on Ngrok and works as expected. I want the same output on ec2 endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

At first we can try do that and it's better you share your code if possible:

- Make sure that your ec2 endpoint is accessible either public or private one but the private one needs more steps than public to access as you know.
- Make sure that your server is running and you have an entry-point to start your requests

Comment: I checked inbound and outbound rules. Without access to the endpoint I wouldve received 403 error. But Here Im getting Internal server error. Tried restarting the server and accessing the endpoint via Public IPv4 address, still no luck.

Comment: Make sure then you've all code dependencies installed and running

Comment: Maybe one of them not installed or working properly, and I think it could be the one handling or mapping your response.